# How can I use System.Windows.Forms in MonoDevelop on Ubuntu?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ubuntu, mono

I met this problem at the beginning of my work. I am using Mono 2.10 with MonoDevelop 2.8.
When I create a new C# project, I can not use:

`using System.Windows.Forms`

because there is no such namespace here.

I searched for some answer and tried:

`apt-get install libmono-system-windows-forms4.0-cil` and

`apt-get install libmono-winforms2.0-cil`

but they all tell me I have installed them. So now I'm wondering if I can not write windows forms application with Mono but I can only run such application with it?

Comment: Not a mono-develop user, but... have you tried adding a reference to the System.Windows.Forms assembly in the IDE?

Comment: I have only looked at mono once, but there is a profile you can install so it targets the Mono framework.  That may be your problem.  You have it installed but it you don't target it or reference it, your application has no knowledge of it

Comment: @Inisheer What you said is indeed the reason... Forgive me that I asked such a stupid question. I was using Visual Studio to directly create windows forms apps and never thought I need to add reference to a empty project. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this was answered in the comments, newbies (like me) might appreciate a more spelled-out version:

- In monodevelop, click the gear/settings icon next to the References folder (or right-click the References folder)
- Select 'Edit References'
- Search for windows
- Check System.Windows.Forms
- Click OK

Answer (score 0):

For **monodevelop 7.8.4**:

Project -> Edit preferences -> Search "windows"

[image]